# how to call a database table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, initialization

im trying to reference one of my tables in my rails app but i get the following error

```
uninitialized constant UsersController::BadgesSashes
```

im in my user controller, and my table is named badges_sashes (according to my database browser)

i cant do something like...

```
BadgesSashes.first
```

in my controller? im using a gem, and i already have a

```
has_merit
```

line in my user model. do i need to do anything else? thank you

Comment: Does your model have name "BadgesSashes"? And what is "has_merit" exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reference a table, you need to define a model with the singular version of the name. So if your table is names `badges_sashes`, than you should create a file `app/models/badges_sash.rb`:

```
class BadgesSash < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Bear in mind that usually goes the other way round: You generate a model and it will create a database migration, a class and a unit test for you.

To learn more, you can do an free online course, in which all these things are explained, called [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/), or read the book [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) or the [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)